# How to set style checkbox/radiobutton when checkbox/radiobutton is focused?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set border for checkbox/radiobutton when it is focused.
Here is my code! Thanks

```
 UIElement element = container;
 DependencyObject obj2 = FocusManager.GetIsFocusScope(element) ? element : 
 FocusManager.GetFocusScope(element);
 IInputElement focusedElement = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(obj2);
 object obj = focusedElement;

 if (obj != null && (obj.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox) || obj.GetType() == 
     typeof(RadioButton)))
   {
  //Set style when focus for Checkbox, radiobutton. 
   }
```

Comment: Why don't you keep it in xaml ? Use triggers.

Comment: Because I have many views, I want to set style for them from base view

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the code

```
 if (obj != null && (obj.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox) || obj.GetType() == 
         typeof(RadioButton)))
       {
         var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
         // element.Style =  Resources["ResourceName"] as Style;
         // or 
         //  element.Style = (Style) FindResource("YourResourceKey");
       }
```

I commented out the line as these are the ways to set style if defined in resources.

Comment: Hi you, I only want to checkbox/radiobutton  have dash border when they are focused.